# Express headers error when sending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

An error "[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" occurs when requesting this method. I just got acquainted with express and quite possibly succeeded in doing something. Tell me what causes the error

```
const generateAccessToken = (id,username) => {
    const payload = {
        id,
        username
    }
    return jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: "24h"});
}



async login(req, res) {
        try {
            const {username, password} = req.body;
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, result) => {
                if(error) return console.log(error);

                result.map(item => {

                    if (item.username !== username) {
                        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Error username'});
                    }

                    const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, item.password);

                     if (!validPassword) {
                        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Error password'});
                    }

                    const token = generateAccessToken(item.id,item.username);
                    return res.json({token});

                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.status(400).json({message: 'Login error'});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to the response inside of your `.map`, so it is writing the headers multiple times, and you're only allowed to do that once.

Quick glance indicates you *probably* want to do something like:

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username', { replacements: { username }})
```

but I'm not sure what sql driver you are using or how it handles binding parameters, or whether you have a unique index on your username column, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain in more detail how to start a loop in the database and store the values ​​instead of "item.username", "" item.id "?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking, but you shouldn't need a loop for what appears to be a login function - you fetch the one row you care about and work with it, no need to check other rows